# How do I detect if a user has touched any part of the screen other than the inside of an EditText?

Tags: android

I am guessing this means making the whole screen touchable. How exactly is that done?

and secondly calculating if an X,Y is within the EditText.

Comment: The question is self explanatory.  Detect if you have touched the screen anywhere BUT within the perimeter of one of the screens ui elements.  So picture an activity with 10 ui controls.  I want to know if the user touched anywhere except on a particular ui control.

Comment: What have I tried?  Something called 'think before you code'

Answer (score 1):

override the onTouchEvent in the activity you want to implement this....and get the X, Y co-ordinates using event.getX() and event.getY()

```
   @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
    return false;
    }
```

but i suggest you must search thoroughly before posting a question.

Comment: And I would suggest you research a bit before answering.  onTOuchEvent at the activity level will not really get called if it touchEvent lands on some contained element like say a CheckBox.  This works if you are using a surface view.  Please update your answer with how to insure that the event gets bubbled all the way up to the container (activity) in every case?

Comment: BTW, I did override this method and it was not envoked at all. FYI

Comment: public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {) seems to be the one called and by getting reference to the main view as :

Comment: LinearLayout myView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayoutId)

Comment: The events from the sub views just don't get up to the container they are gobbled by the sub views like check boxes atc.

Comment: The question is not as easy as it appear Archie.